# angular ui-bootstrap accordion how to achieve customized behavior: default all close, when clicking one accordion-group heading, open all others

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with ui-bootstrap accordion. I have an accordion inside an accordion. [image]

under the 1st accordion 'Category', I have another accordion, with 3 accordion- group. They are closed by default. I would like this behavior: when you click an accordion group title (say 'fruit'), if all the accordion groups are closed, then it will open them all... but if any groups is open( say if any of the 'fruit', 'meat', and vegetable' is open when user is clicking), then when you click, it will toggle the clicked accordion-group. you can check out the plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UcETfOVh8RwMX40mOCVv?p=preview

my html and angular code is follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <body ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion >
      <accordion-group>
        <accordion-heading> Category</accordion-heading>

        <accordion ng-repeat="(category, items) in categories" close-others="oneAtATime" is-open="true">
          <accordion-group >
            <accordion-heading ><div>{{category}}</div></accordion-heading>

            <div ng-repeat="item in items.data">{{item}}</div>
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>

      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>

  </body>

</html>


angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.categories = {
    fruit: {
      data: {
        apple: 3,
        orange: 5,
       lemon: 6
      },
      toggled: false

    },
    vegetable: {
      data: {
         lettuce: 1,
        broccoli: 5, 
        spinach: 4
      },
      toggled: false

    },
    meat: {
      data: {
        chicken: 3,
        beef: 6,
        lamb: 8
      },
      toggled: false

    }
  };
}
```

How can I achieve such behavior? I have work progress in another plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9eTfpn81g57Dk4FtVSlA?p=preview 
I've explored with 'is-open' attribute in accordion, I've tried to refered to the $parent, not producing the behavior i want.

Comment: I have work progress in another plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9eTfpn81g57Dk4FtVSlA?p=preview I've explored with 'is-open' attribute in accordion, I've tried to refered to the $parent, not producing the behavior i want. seems to open and close all the tabs at the same time.

Comment: I believe it has to do with line 18 on the index.html, is-open="", but i don't know exactly what to enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by bobleujr `is-open` should work. But the code is a bit tricky and I'm not sure if there is an easier solution.

The problem is that the `ng-click` where I'm adding my 'toggleAll' check is called after toggeling the clicked accordion.
So I have to track the previous accordion state to be sure that we have to toggle all accordions. I'm doing this by looping over all accodions states and count if it is open.

Then I can check later if `previousCount == 0` and `currentCount==1` we need to open all.

I don't like doing two for loops for the behaviour but I think that's the only way to do it.

If it wouldn't toggle the state with `ng-click` it would be easier to do. But I don't know how. I've tried to disable the `is-open` toggle of the accordion directive but that wasn't working.

[Decorating](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/) of the accordion directive could help then you could add the check before toggeling. But that's probably not that easy.

Please have a look at the demo below or here in the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jh18bhZU9cAl1FcOj2e0?p=preview).

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', AccordionDemoCtrl);

function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  var prevOpenCount = 0;
  
  $scope.toggle = function(index) {
        var openCount = 0,
            openAll = false;
        
        // check how many accordions are open
        for( var i=0; i < $scope.openState.length; i++ ){
          if ($scope.openState[i] === true) {
              openCount++;
          }
        }
        
        if ( openCount === 1 && prevOpenCount === 0) { // open all
          for( var i=0; i < $scope.openState.length; i++ ){
            $scope.openState[i] = true;
          }
        }
       
        //console.log(index, $scope.openState, openCount, prevOpenCount);
        prevOpenCount = openCount;
      };
      
  $scope.categories = {
    fruit: {
      data: {
        apple: 3,
        orange: 5,
       lemon: 6
      },
      toggled: false
      
    },
    vegetable: {
      data: {
         lettuce: 1,
        broccoli: 5, 
        spinach: 4
      },
      toggled: false
     
    },
    meat: {
      data: {
        chicken: 3,
        beef: 6,
        lamb: 8
      },
      toggled: false
      
    }
  };
  

  $scope.openState = new Array(Object.keys($scope.categories).length); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    
    <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    --><script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    
    <accordion>
      <accordion-group>
        <accordion-heading> Category</accordion-heading>
        
        <accordion ng-repeat="(category, items) in categories" close-others="oneAtATime">
          <accordion-group ng-click="toggle($index, $event)" is-open="openState[$index]">
            
            <accordion-heading ><div><!--{{openState}}-->{{category}}</div></accordion-heading>
            
            <div ng-repeat="item in items.data">{{item}}</div>
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
        
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
  </div>
```

Comment: btw, what does the $event in toggle($index, $event) do though, not quite sure.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the `$event`. It's not needed.  I only tried to prevent the click event of the accordion but that wasn't working. If you would add the second parameter to `$scope.toggle` you could do things like `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

WABBIT0111

you may want to use the attribute `is-open=ctrlVar`.

This way you will be able to set it with a `ng-click=action to change ctrlVar state` and then toggle them back to original position.

Comment: this i have tried. please checkout http://plnkr.co/edit/9eTfpn81g57Dk4FtVSlA?p=preview. on line 18 of the script file, i've ried both items.toggled, $parent.items.toggled, and $parent.parent.items.toggled, non seem to yield the behavior i desire.